# Copy Log file from docker container to host giving no such file or directory

Tags: docker, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, docker-volume

I am running Jmeter test from docker container. Test is triggered from Jenkins. I need to get the jmeter log from bin folder copied to local host. But getting no such file or directory.Any idea why this is happening. I am able to copy from container folder other than bin.

Relevant code snipper is given below.

docker file:

```
.....
.....
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/share/jmeter/bin/script.sh"]
```

jenkinsfile

```
................
................
        stage('Run Test') {
        steps {                     
            sh 'docker build -t mycontainer . \
                        && docker run -v /home/jenkins/workspace/test_feature_test:\
                        /usr/share/jmeter/bin mycontainer '             
               }
        }
```

Comment: I could copy the log file using the docker command docker run mycontainer /usr/share/jmeter/bin/jmeter.log > /home/jenkins/workspace/test_feature_test/jmeter.log.

Answer (score 0):

I think givne you're using [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#volume) you can copy only the files which exists in the image by the time when container is created.

Consider switching to [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

A better option could be using [Jenkins Docker Build-Controller](https://community.jenkins.io/t/jenkins-docker-build-controller/2236), on this case you will be able to publish artifacts, use [Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jenkins-performance-plugin), etc.